# IIS Redirect - Redirect to new site except specif page

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting

In my site , I have to write IIS redirect rule and condtion are

If page URL contains **".jp/en/anypage"**  or **".jp/JP/anypage"** then redirect to new-Site 
except URL contains "**jp/slide/evenity**" or "**jp/slide/xyz**" then stay on same site.

I write below three rules but rule # 3 is blocking rule 1 and 2 :- suggest the approach

```
<rule name="www-mysite-co-jp - Redirect 1">
                             <match url="^jp/slide/evenity/login\/$" />  
                             <conditions>
                               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?preview.mysite.co\.jp$" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="https://preview.mysite.co.jp/slide/evenity/login/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule> 
                <rule name="www-mysite-co-jp - Redirect 2">
                             <match url="^jp/slide/xyz/login\/$" />  
                             <conditions>
                               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?preview.mysite.co\.jp$" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="https://preview.mysite.co.jp/slide/xyz/login/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule> 

                <rule name="www-mysite-co-jp - Redirect 3">
                             <match url="^(jp|en)/(.*)$" />  
                             <conditions>
                               <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?preview.mysite.co\.jp$" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="https://preview.new.co.jp/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
```

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://blog.lextudio.com/iis-url-rewrite-tip-break-free-adccdb4b9f2f

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite

`preview.mysite.co.jp/(en|jp)/anypage to https://preview.new.co.jp/ and rewrite`

```
 preview.mysite.co.jp/jp/slide/(evenity|xyz）(.*)------>https://preview.mysite.co.jp/slide/(evenity|xyz)(.*)
```

Please try this. You need to whitelist evenity and xyz for rule #3

```
<rule name="www-mysite-co-jp - Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
                             <match url="^jp/slide/evenity(.*)$" />  
                             <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?preview.mysite.co\.jp$" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="https://preview.mysite.co.jp/slide/evenity{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule> 
                <rule name="www-mysite-co-jp - Redirect 2" stopProcessing="true">
                             <match url="^jp/slide/xyz(.*)$" />  
                             <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?preview.mysite.co\.jp$" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="https://preview.mysite.co.jp/slide/xyz{R:1}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule> 

                <rule name="www-mysite-co-jp - Redirect 3" stopProcessing="true">
                             <match url="^(jp|en)/(.*)$" />  
                             <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?preview.mysite.co\.jp$" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/jp/slide/(evenity|xyz)(.*)" negate="true" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="https://preview.new.co.jp/" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Permanent" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>
```

Of course , rule #1 and #2 can be mixed.

```
 <rule name="www-mysite-co-jp - Redirect 1" stopProcessing="true">
                             <match url="^jp/slide/(evenity|xyz)(.*)$" />  
                             <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?preview.mysite.co\.jp$" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="http://preview.mysite.co.jp/slide/{R:1}{R:2}" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule> 

                <rule name="www-mysite-co-jp - Redirect 3" stopProcessing="true">
                             <match url="^(jp|en)/(.*)$" />  
                             <conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^.*\.?preview.mysite.co\.jp$" />
                        <add input="{URL}" pattern="^/jp/slide/(evenity|xyz)(.*)" negate="true" />
                             </conditions>
                             <action type="Redirect" url="http://preview.new.co.jp/" appendQueryString="false" logRewrittenUrl="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
                </rule>
```